# ChartJS - Size of the point doesn't change

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I created this chart, and set `usePointStyle: true` to use circles instead rectangles for the labels of `legend`. But I can't seem to change the size (or *radius*) of these circles.

In the documents [it says](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html#legend-label-configuration),

> Label style will match corresponding point style (size is based on the
>   **mimimum** value between boxWidth and fontSize).

So in my example, the size of *point style* must be `min(5, 12) = 5`, thus increasing `boxWidth` must increase its size (until `boxWidth` is greater than `fontSize`). But that's not the case; changing `boxWidth` doesn't have any affect.

How can I fix this? Also, is it possible to fill these circles with their color?

```js
let chLine = document.getElementById("chLine");

let chartData = {
  labels: ['l1', 'l2', 'l3', 'l4', 'l5', 'l6', 'l7', 'l8', 'l9'],
  datasets: [{
      label: 'c1',
      data: [0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.35, 0.2, 0.5, 0.4, 0.55, 0.6],
      backgroundColor: 'transparent',
      borderColor: '#e6194b',
      borderWidth: 1,
      pointBackgroundColor: '#e6194b'
    },
    {
      label: 'c2',
      data: [0.7, 0.5, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.1, 0.88, 0.35, 0.45],
      backgroundColor: 'transparent',
      borderColor: '#3cb44b',
      borderWidth: 1,
      pointBackgroundColor: '#3cb44b'
    }
  ]
}

if (chLine) {
  new Chart(chLine, {
    type: 'line',
    data: chartData,
    options: {
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: false
          }
        }]
      },
      legend: {
        position: 'top',
        labels: {
          fontSize: 12,
          boxWidth: 5,
          usePointStyle: true
        }
      },
      events: ['click', 'mousemove'],
      onClick: clicked
    }
  });
}

function clicked(c, i) {
  console.log(c, i)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>test</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row my-3">
      <div class="col">
        <h4>Chart</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row my-2">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <canvas id="chLine" height="100"></canvas>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.js"></script>
  <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To increase the size of the point, you will have to increase the legend's `fontSize` value. When you increase the font-size both the label and the point's size will increase.

When you increase the `boxWidth` the overall width that the legend icon takes will increase. In the case of the 'box' legend icon, the rectangle's width will increase. But in case of point, all it will do is provide some extra space between the legend icon and its text.

To make the legend point circle fill with their color, you will have to set the `backgroundColor` property to that color and `fill` to false.

```
  datasets: [{
      label: 'c1',
      data: [0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.35, 0.2, 0.5, 0.4, 0.55, 0.6],
      backgroundColor: '#e6194b',
      borderColor: '#e6194b',
      borderWidth: 1,
      fill: false,
      pointBackgroundColor: '#e6194b'
    },
    {
      label: 'c2',
      data: [0.7, 0.5, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.1, 0.88, 0.35, 0.45],
      backgroundColor: '#3cb44b',
      borderColor: '#3cb44b',
      borderWidth: 1,
      fill: false,
      pointBackgroundColor: '#3cb44b'
    }
  ]
```